# How to make python looping logic faster

Tags: python

## High-level Goal

I have a task with a duration of 5 which can start between time point 0 and 10
Also, I have breaks in intervals [2, 4) , and [6, 7) in the horizon [0, 10).

Whenever a task is starting at a particular time point, it should check the break time and extend the duration such that it completes its actual duration. For example, if a task start at say time point 1, ideally it should be completed by time point 6. but due to breaks at 2,3 and 6 it should be extended till 9 to complete the task. That means, duration = 5 + 3 = 8.

Following is the duration of task at each time point considering the breaks
[8, 8, -1, -1, 6, 6, -1, 5, 5, 5]
I use -1 to forbid this as a starting point at break time point.
The above example is for your understanding of the logic I am trying to establish and code.

## Specific Problem

I could solve this by defining a function as follows. For the above small data it works well. But if my horizon is longer say 86400 (two months in minutes), and my number of breaks are higher (say 2 breaks on each day of 4 hours), then my looping is taking more time.

```
Invalid_Timings2 = [
    (0, 8640, 10080),
    (0, 18720, 20160),
    (0, 28800, 30240),
    ...
    (44, 59040, 60480),
    (44, 69120, 70560),
    (44, 79200, 80640)
    ]

def Duration_Pre_Compute_Task_Split(Invalid_Timings2):
    Duration1 = []
    original_task_duration = 1380   # My task duration is 1380 minutes
    for h in xrange(0, 86400):      # task can start anywhere between 0 to 86400 minutes
        dur = original_task_duration
        k=0
        for t in Invalid_Timings2: # break timings given at the end [(0,480,600), (0,960, 1200) etc..]
            # current time point h should be outside break range
            # also new duration calculated should not fall into next break range similar to the case explained with small data.
            # If it falls, this break time should be added to the calculated duration
            if t[1] - dur <= h <= t[1]+ dur and h not in range(t[1], t[2]) and h < t[2]: 
                k = 1
                dur += t[2] - t[1]
        if k != 0:  #if k=1 means h is not in break range, task cannot start during break range
           Duration1.append((h,dur)) # for each time point, final calculated duration is appended.
    return Duration1
```

My issue is about the performance. If my horizon is longer and number of breaks are increasing as per the horizon, this computation time is increasing exponentially.

How can I improve this function to reduce the calculation times?

Comment: This question is too general, more like a homework problem that you need to be done. You can improve it by adding what you have tried. Also, you should focus on the specific part of the problem that you're stuck with.

Comment: Hi, its not a homework problem. It's very small part of a scheduling application. And I did whatever I could to improve it. Earlier, it used to take one hour and i got it to 15 mins by reducing the unnecessary steps. I just want to know expert opinion if it can be improved. Let me know what I can add so that you can see the problem yourself

Comment: Try making this more specific. For example, the function you show has duration 1380, but your text says only 5. The function loops to 86400, but that's not explained anywhere. Also try adding some comments to the function to help us understand what you're trying.

Comment: updated as per your suggestion. I took small data to explain the logic and since performance is my issue, I kept large data as part of the code so that some of you might execute on your side. Can I add a large list for Invalid_Timings2 in the above code?

Comment: Since the code already works, shouldn't this be in code review?

Comment: If the code has God-awful performance, it's not working. The question isn't looking for style or minor improvements, but for a structurally different way to calculate the output.

Answer (score 0):

A micro-optimization would be to unpack `t` to variables to avoid the repeated look-ups.  e.g.:

```
    for t in Invalid_Timings2:
        t0, t1, t2 = t
        if t1 - dur <= h <= t1 + dur and h not in range(t1, t1 + t2) and t0==10 and h < t1 + t2:
            k = 1
            dur += t2
```

This replaces 9 lookups with a single unpacking

Answer (score 0):

Your performance problem comes from very large nested loops (`h`, then `t`) with semi-complex logic at the core (an `if` statement with element lookups, calculations, range creation, etc.).

Here is a way to get rid of the loops and the `if` statement:

```
def Duration_Pre_Compute_Task_Split(Invalid_Timings2):
    original_task_duration = 5

    # start with list assuming no delays
    Duration1 = [original_task_duration] * 10

    # work backward, updating all durations based on each invalid timing
    for t in reversed(Invalid_Timings2):
        # unpack once (thanks Brian)
        t0, stt, end = t
        delay = end - stt

        # any duration between stt/end -> invalid
        Duration1[stt:end] = [-1] * delay

        # any duration before stt -> delayed
        # (everything from 0 to stt is the same, so just use the first element)
        Duration1[:stt] = [Duration1[0] + delay] * stt

    return Duration1
```

This worked ok with your high-level example (0-10). You'll need to test/tweak it for your real application obviously. Let me know if you have any questions about how it works. Good luck!

Comment: Your statement saying that "any duration before stt -> delayed" is not correct. Only if the duration is falling into the invalid time range then it will get delayed. Assume it as a machine, We can process on the machine only in valid timings. machine will be down in break times. so the job will take extra time for which the machine is unavailable. If machine is available for given duration, there won't be any delay. You can check this by changing the original_task_duration to 2 in your code. Since the first break starts from 2, task will not get delayed when we start at 0.